# Get thumbnail of PDF page using itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

Using itextsharp, How can I get the thumbnails of Pages and display in a picturebox. 
there are hundreds of samples on net using iTextsharp but 99% of them are how to create and manipulate PDF not just read PDF.

```
// pdfFileName is the file Name
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFileName);
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
{  
// I need something like PdfPage here
}
```

Can someone suggest how to do this? I've had a look at the itext docs and can't figure out where to get started and get a PDF Page , I assumed I need PdfImageObject but how to get there...

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iText and iTextSharp are PDF generators only unfortunately, and what you are looking for is actually PDF renderer. According to Bruno Lowagie the creator of iText in a [recent blog post](http://lowagie.com/pdfviewer) they have no plan on doing so any time soon, either.

[PDF Clown](http://www.stefanochizzolini.it/en/projects/clown/), which is still only in a very early alpha, has a [blog post](http://pdfclown.wordpress.com/2010/09/23/waiting-for-pdf-clown-0-1-release/) (see point #3) stating that they've got a partial renderer working so I'd recommend looking at that.

Otherwise take a look at these SO posts about converting PDFs to JPGs:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711942/convert-pdf-file-to-jpg-asp-net
- [Converting a multiple-page PDF to a single image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680948/converting-a-multiple-page-pdf-to-a-single-image)

The `PdfImageObject` object that you were looking at is used to create an "image-like" object that represents a piece of raw PDF content that can be embedded within a PDF but has no methods for creating a raster image such as JPG or BMP so it wouldn't help you. But if you're curious about it see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280622/create-an-image-or-pdftemplate-from-a-pdf-file).

Comment: can you give me the sample code for converting pdf pages into images using PDF Clown. Actually i downloaded the pdf clown lib project.How to add an exeutable solution which references the lib project...

Comment: Sorry @Saravanan, I've never actually used PDF Clown, I've only heard other people talking about it

Answer (score 1):

Check this link to extract an image...[Extract images using iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802269/itextsharp-extract-images)
I have modified this code to extract a form(Table an is data) so i guess you can extract what you want with a little of work :)